# A question about "*(++p)->t", "*++p->t" and "++*p->t"

Tags: c, pointers

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char u[] = "UVWXYZ";
    char v[] = "xyz";
    struct T {
        int x;
        char c;
        char *t;
    } a[] = {{11, 'A', u}, {100, 'B', v}}, *p = a;

    p = a;
    printf("*(++p)->t = %c\n", *(++p)->t);
    p = a;
    printf("*++p->t = %c\n", *++p->t);
    p = a;
    printf("++*p->t = %c\n", ++*p->t);
}
```

the result is:

```
*(++p)->t = x
*++p->t = V
++*p->t = W
```

Well, I thought `*(++p)` and `*++p` is the same because the pointer will be incremented first. But why do `*(++p)->t` and `*++p->t` have different result?
Also, I thought `++*p` means the pointer point to `u[0]`, and that is `'U'`, then `'U'` will be incremented. So I thought the result should be `'V'`?

Comment: No one sane would write code like that. You would write something like `for(p=a; p!=NULL; p++) { ... *(p->t) ... }`.

Comment: I definitely know that,  but it's an assignment that confused me so much… It's as confusing as `i=i++`... In real project,  I would never write like that, but I had to handle my exam first…

Comment: @ArcherSore Teaching things like this level of detail in operator precedence tells me your teacher has nothing better to teach.  Writing code like this is **horrible** because your brain **will** make mistakes - you should never write code that depends on operator precedence to this level of detail.  And since you can't really rely on your brain to get it right **every single time**, it's not really useful to learn the details of operator precedence down to this level of detail.  In short, you have a limited teacher who really isn't very good.  Sturgeon's Law strikes again.

Comment: Make sure to accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `*(++p)->t` is evaluated as `*((++p)->t)` as the indirection operator `*` has lower  [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `->`.  You increment `p` so now points to `a[1]` and return the correcting `*t` which is `v[0]`.

   You subsequently reset `p = a` in the next line.
2. `*++p->t` is evaluated as `*(++(p->t))` because the prefix operator `++` has a lower precedence than `->`, and while the prefix operator `++` and indirection `*` have the same precedence they are right-to-left associative.  The effect is advancing is setting `a[0].u = &u[1]` and you print the value `u[1]`.
3. `++*p->t` is evaluated as `++(*(p->t))` and the effect is incrementing the value stored at `u[1]` so it's now the next letter `'W'`.

Prefer unit tests to be independent.  The choice of your string test data is not great as you cannot tell from a `%c` if you advance the pointer or incremented the value `*(u+1) == (*u) + 1`.

Comment: I think I've figured out this question now. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I've understood...I make a mistake!

1. `*(++p)->t`
   `++p`：so p point to {100, 'B', v}
   `->t`：point to the string v
   `*`：get v[0], and that is x
2. `*++p->t`
   `p->t`：point to the string u
   `++p->t`：point to u[0]
   `*`：get the value of u[0] = 'V'
3. `++*p->t`
   `p->t`：point to the string u
   `*p->t`：get the value of u[0] = 'U'
   `++*p->t`：'U' is incremented, so `u = "VVWXYZ"`

but why the 3rd expression output 'W' in my code?
The answer is in the 2nd expression, `++p->t` make `a[0].t = "VWXYZ"`!

Comment: You should tweak 2 to match your understanding: ++p->t：point to u[1].